# The user count in chat doesn't add up

Tags: support, chat

It's pretty obvious that the number of users displayed doesn't add up.  What's going on?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When you hover over the elements, you'll see what the numbers mean:

[image]

[image]

There may be more users/rooms available, but only a limited number of them have been active within the last number of minutes.

Comment: It's still confusing - why do I need to hover over everything to know what the cryptic numbers mean?

Comment: @bjb568: Not _everything_... Look on the bright side: The information is there, it's just not immediately apparent.

Comment: Has nobody heard of simplicity? The system *can be improved*, so it should be. I didn't say that it was "bad" now. I didn't say that complex systems don't need complex interfaces. I said that it was confusing.

Comment: I don't think it's unheard of for notification counts to refer to activity rather than absolutes.